# Asp.net binding with datatable

Tags: asp.net, database, telerik, scheduler

Here is my code:

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource1" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="name=myEntities" DefaultContainerName="myEntities" 
     EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" 
     EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="FirstTable">
</asp:EntityDataSource>

<asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="name=myEntities" DefaultContainerName="myEntities" 
     EnableDelete="True" EnableFlattening="False" EnableInsert="True" 
     EnableUpdate="True" EntitySetName="SecondTable">
</asp:EntityDataSource>


<telerik:RadScheduler ID="MyCalendar" runat="server" DataEndField="DateTo" DataKeyField="ID"
            DataStartField="DateFrom" DataSubjectField="Description" SelectedView="MonthView"
            OnClientFormCreated="schedulerFormCreated" 
            StartInsertingInAdvancedForm="True"
            AppointmentStyleMode="Default">

     <ResourceTypes>
     <telerik:ResourceType KeyField="ID" Name="FirstTable" TextField="FirstTableName" 
     ForeignKeyField="FirstTableID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" />
     <telerik:ResourceType KeyField="ID" Name="SecondTable" TextField="SecondTableName" 
     ForeignKeyField="SecondTableID" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource2" />
     </ResourceTypes>
    <ResourceStyles>
         <telerik:ResourceStyleMapping Type="FirstTable" ApplyCssClass="rsCategoryGreen" />
    </ResourceStyles>
</telerik:RadScheduler>
```

However, in my scheduler, the appointments I get from FirstTable aren't green. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the "Text" property in the ResourceStyleMapping. This text corresponds to the value of the custom resource. Please take a look at [this demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/examples/resources/defaultcs.aspx) and [this help article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/scheduler-appearance-setting-appointment-style.html) for more information.